# "Тише воды(,) ниже травы" - нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

С одной стороны, "тише воды(,) ниже травы" - это фразеологизм, но с другой, по идее, тут нужна запятая. Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна оно тут, или он является неразрывным оборотом?
Спасибо

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да, это можно считать фразеологизмом, но это совсем не мешает наличию запятой в данном случае. Запятые во фразеологизмах обычно опускаются при противопоставлении с союзами **и** или **ни** ("и так и сяк", "ни жив ни мертв"), а тут обычное бессоюзное перечисление однородных составляющих.